# Postgres: Aggregate Average for each min of data

Tags: postgresql

I currently have a query that returns the datetime, and value from a table.

```
Select time, value from table;

2014-02-05 15:49:54.458 70
2014-02-05 15:49:55.46  70
2014-02-05 15:49:56.483 70
2014-02-05 15:49:57.487 70
2014-02-05 15:49:58.503 70
2014-02-05 15:50:00.042 70
2014-02-05 15:50:01.546 70
2014-02-05 15:50:03.056 70
2014-02-05 15:50:04.093 70
```

What I am looking to do is something like

```
select average(value) from table group by (cast time to min resolution)time;

2014-02-05 15:49    70
2014-02-05 15:50    70
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select date_trunc('minute', time), 
       avg(value)
from the_table
group by date_trunc('minute', time)
order by date_trunc('minute', time);
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

---

<sup>Btw: `time` and `value` are horrible names for a column</sup>

Comment: Great answer got it working. Vars were chosen juts for example, feel free to edit and change if desired.